# JavaScript Proxy - Add other properties intermediately

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my proxy:

```
const handler = {
    get: function(target, key) {
        const next = target.object[key];

        if (typeof next === 'object' && next !== null) {
            return new Proxy({object: next}, handler)
        } else {
            return next;
        }
    }
}
const proxy = new Proxy({object: someObj}, handler);
```

Basically, I like to append other metadata, but when returning the value, I want the original result to be returned back. In here, I'm storing the actual object under `object` key, and later will be adding other data to Proxy.

This works fine, but unfortunately, the object passed is no longer passed by reference, i.e.

```
const proxy ...

// would log say "myName"
console.log(proxy.users[0].name);

proxy.users[0] = someOtherUser;
// Still logs "myName"
console.log(proxy.users[0].name);
```

How come?

Comment: Have you tried making a deep clone of `someObj` so that the array isn't still being referenced?

Comment: You need a set handler as well that sets values on `target.object` instead of the proxy.

Comment: Without that `proxy.users[0] = someOtherUser;` adds a `0` property to the proxy return by `proxy.users` instead of setting the value on the underlying object.

Comment: @Paulpro: Make it an answer.

Comment: @FelixKling I would if I weren't on my phone right now. I don't like typing up answers on my phone because I can't run stack snippets, and it takes a while to indent code properly. Maybe I will later, if no one else does first.

Comment: @Paulpro: I deleted my draft after I saw your comment ;) I understand...

Comment: @Paulpro thanks! Worked great. Post it and I'll mark it.